# HDD in  idle system stays active

Tags: 11.10, hardware, hard-drive, services

When having Ubuntu 11.10 idle, hard-disk is still doing "something" periodically for a very small time (I have 8GB RAM). I can hear the seeks every few seconds (`iostat` tells something like 20kB/s).

What process could cause that? I thought that's a Windows issue only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `iotop` to look at what processes are doing I/O.

Comment: Have an idea what is COMMAND `[jdb2/sda1-8]`?

Comment: [jdb2] is a kernel process responsible for writing the journal in your filesystem. Perhaps syslogd is doing writes,  cron.log or something?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the computer into power save mode:

```
sudo pm-powersave true
```

Less frequent writes to the disk means if you crash you can lose more work though.